# how to fetch text data from website and storing as excel file using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, automation, scripting

I want to create a script that fetches the all the data in the following website : https://www.bis.doc.gov/dpl/dpl.txt and store it in a excel file and count the number of records in it, using python language. I've tried to achieve by implementing the code as:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.bis.doc.gov/dpl/dpl.txt"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

I've fetched the data but didn't know the next step of storing it as excel file. Anyone pls guide or share your valuable ideas. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with pandas easily. Since the data is in tab seperated value.

Note: `openpyxl` needs to be installed for this to work.

```
import requests
import io
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://www.bis.doc.gov/dpl/dpl.txt"
page = requests.get(URL)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(page.text), sep="\t")
df.to_excel(r'i_data.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother for valuable time in sharing this! It really worked superbly :)